# Calculating the average of only the odd numbers

Tags: java, average

Given the case where I need to sum all the odd numbers from 1 to 100 and in the end print the result and also the average, how do I get to the average, once it's only adding the odd ones, so I cannot just divide it for the upperbound, which is 100? Many thanks!

Comment: Two pieces to this problem: (1) create a List of only odd integers in some range, (2) calculate average.  You don't calculate averages by dividing by the upper bound.  This is an EASY problem.

Comment: Sounds like you don't know what an "average" is.

Comment: You may use a stream if you like. Like an IntStream and a filter for odd numbers. In case you think PEF’s comment to one of the answers counts as cheating (I don’t).

Answer (score 4):

The average (or arithmetic mean as your question implies) of a group of numbers is the sum of those values divided by the size of the group.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average

So, to find the average, you sum all the odd numbers from 1 to 100, and divide by the total number of odd numbers from 1 to 100.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the following code:

```
    int sum = 0;

    for(int i=0; i<50; i++) {
        sum += 2*i + 1;    // += 1, 3, 5, 7, ..., 97, 99
    }

    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    System.out.println("average = " + (sum/50));
```

Comment: ... or just realize the sum of the first 50 positive odd numbers is really just (1+99) + (3+97) + (5+95) + ... + (49 + 51) = 25*(100) = 2500 and 2500/50 = 50.